# Galeria de imagens com Carousel Boostrap. nome.jpg separadas por , no db!

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou querendo criar uma galeria de imagens usando o carousel do bootstrap, ao salvar as multiplas imagens no db elas vão para a mesma coluna "fotos" e são separadas por "." (foto1.jpg,foto2.jpg,foto3.jpg) agora eu desejo exibi-lás em com o carousel.

```
          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="uploads/<?php echo $foto_thumb; ?>" width="560px" alt="...">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="uploads/image.php" width="560px" alt="...">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Explique mais o problema. AS fotos estao separadas por virgula, e voce deseja exibir individualmente?

Comment: campo id e campo fotos no campo fotos tem várias separadas por "," (foto1.jpg,foto2.jpg)agora eu quero exbir todas elas no carousel foto1.jpg NEXT foto2.jpg ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha, se pelo que entendi. Voce tem um campo com várias fotos, e quer separa-las agora. Com o `explode` da para remover as virgulas e transformar em um array, com todas as fotos separadas. Assim:

```
  <?php
$imagens_nome =  "7263273813.jpg,737862834.jpg,236276322.jpg";
$imagens=explode(',',$imagens_nome);
foreach($imagens as $img){
echo "Imagem: ".$img."<br>";
}

?>
```

Aplicando ao carousel, acredito que ficaria algo desse tipo:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <?php
    $cont=0;
     foreach($imagens as $img){?>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?php echo $cont;?>" class="<?php echo ($cont==0)?" active ":" ";?>"></li>
    <?php $cont++;} ?>

  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <?php 
      $cont=0;
     foreach($imagens as $img){?>
    <div class="item <?php echo ($cont==0)?" active ":" ";?>">
      <img src="uploads/<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php $cont++; }  ?> 
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Se for isso, basta inserir no seu código, nao ficou muito claro como quer fazer... Caso ainda tenha dificuldade, só comentar

Comment: A parte em que estou tendo problemas é em adaptar o carousel para inserir estas imagens, pois não bastar colocar a variavel $img em "src="uploads/$img" eu preciso adaptar o carousel para passar para seguinte imagem da mesma galeria.

Comment: @Paulo o que nao está dando certo exatamente? Vou tentar editar com o que entendi...

Comment: @Paulo editei minha resposta, ve se dessa forma funciona. Caso nao de, comente e se possivel passe o link do carousel que esta tentando implementar, para ficar mais facil de te ajudar

Comment: [http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel] o código mostra as imagens uma abaixo da outra, acredito ter alterar os indicadores, como guardei as imagens todas na mesma coluna no db, saberia como fazer caso estivesse uma imagem por coluna. "Obg pela atenção"

Comment: @Paulo editei, tenta dessa forma... `$imagens`no caso é o array com as imagens, como citei na resposta

Comment: funcionou, no entanto o botão next e Previous não funciona. apenas se usar as setas do teclado.

Comment: @Paulo olha se voce colocou o jquery corretamente e tal.. e se funcionou marque como resposta :)'